# What would cause a pending Ethereum tx to not show up on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, pending-transactions, nonce

I am using the Web3 2.0 library to call `web3.eth.sendTransaction` and send Ether from one address to another.

When I check the nonce of my wallet in my program using the following web3 functions, it shows that I have multiple pending transactions

`await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, 'pending');` 1005

`await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);` 1000

But these pending transactions are not showing on Etherscan. Once I send a transaction from Metamask with a custom nonce, all 5 of my pending transactions go through at once.

Why are my pending transactions not being picked up by Etherscan?

Comment: Etherscan is a private company. You should reach out to their customer support service.

Comment: Sure, but there might be a reason technically like "Eth txs with a gasprice set to 0 are discarded by some nodes" or whatever

Comment: Yup, that's why I didn't vote for this question to be closed. But most likely this is related to the Etherscan indexing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an RPC that is not up to date, it will show as pending in your Metamask but never resolve, and eventually be dropped.